# Calling out Ranges as String with a Dynamic Variable

Tags: excel, vba

I got a code here while researching on how to add cells based on a criteria to a defined range. This was the code:

```
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim c As Range
Set rng1 = Range("N1:N10")

 For Each c In rng1
' Add cells to rng2 if it is highlighted with a certain color
If c.Interior.ColorIndex = 43
    If Not rng2 Is Nothing Then
        Set rng2 = Union(rng2, c)
    Else
    ' the first valid cell becomes rng2
        Set rng2 = c
    End If
End If
Next
```

What I plan on doing with the retrieved cell was to get the value and add them. My initial plan was to use the formula SUM() where the range of the sum is the 
supposed rng2. In order for me to put it in this formula, I'd have to extract the cells from the retrieved range. So upon research, I stumbled upon this code:

```
Function RangeToString(ByVal myRange As Range) As String
RangeToString = ""
If Not myRange Is Nothing Then
    Dim myCell As Range
    For Each myCell In myRange
        RangeToString = RangeToString & ";" & myCell.Value
    Next myCell
    'Remove extra comma
    RangeToString = Right(RangeToString, Len(RangeToString) - 1)
End If
End Function
```

With the following functions and codes, I did a test run just to check if it picked up any of the highlighted cells. Sadly, It didn't post any value on the test cell I coded. Here's the sample code I did:

```
 Dim totalsum As String
 totalsum = RangeToString(rng2)
 ThisWorkbook.Sheets("format").Range("N" & counter).Value = totalsum
```

Thanks in advance! Sorry for the lengthy question.

Answer (score 0):

If all you're needing is the sum of `rng2`, you can just use use `Worksheetfunction.Sum()` and use `rng2` as the argument.

```
Debug.print WorksheetFunction.Sum(rng2)
```

No need to parse out the individual values of each cell in the range to use in the worksheet.